# Can't create VF with vfio-pci via sysfs

Tags: dpdk

Using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and and DPDK 21.02 and following DPDK doc, I performed these commands

```
sudo modprobe vfio-pci enable_sriov=1
dpdk-devbind.py --bind=vfio-pci 0000:02:00.0
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/sriov_numvfs
```

but trying to create a VF I have this error

```
alessio@ganimede:~$ sudo su
root@ganimede:/home/alessio# echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/sriov_numvfs
bash: echo: write error: No such file or directory
```

even in this way

```
cd /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0
echo 1 > sriov_numvfs
```

even if /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/sriov_numvfs exist.
NOTE: with dmesg I see this error

```
[ 1071.155309] vfio-pci 0000:02:00.0: Driver does not support SRIOV configuration via sysfs
```

If I try without binding vfio-pci driver but just using kernel one (ixgbe), it works.
But using these VF as DPDK ports on my process, it doesn't work, I have to check but seems that packets are not more received.

NOTE: without VF my DPDK process works using vfio-pci driver.

**NEW INFO:** In this way it works! There was a bug, MAC was wrong and using VF this bug caused application failure. So the question loose part of its interest, in this way works, just the curiosity to know why suggested procedure on DPDK docs does not work.

It is an HOST OS, NIC info are:

```
driver: ixgbe
version: 5.1.0-k
firmware-version: 0x800003e1
```

cat /proc/cmdline

```
BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic root=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ro maybe-ubiquity default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=8 hugepagesz=2M hugepages=1024 intel_iommu=on iommu=pt isolcpus=2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: can you please share the following information, is the OS host or guest OS, what are kernel cmdline, what is NIC being used? firmware used? as per the  question, vfio create is failing on OS or DPDK pF creating VF fails?

Comment: are there any updates?

Answer (score 1):

I think, this is not universally true any more. [This](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html) says "Since Linux version 5.7, the vfio-pci module supports the creation of virtual functions."

Comment: @alamhldr, thanks this will be useful. Since the PMD is mentioned as ixgbe can you please try it on `82599, X522`. I have access only to X710. There is update from the author on the kernel version as `5.4.0-72-generic` also.

Comment: @amlanhdr I have tried the kernel `5.11.0-34-generic` with `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS`. Result for X710 `# lspci -ks 0000:00:0a.0 | grep use
        Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci# ls /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000\:00\:0a.0/sriov_numvfs
ls: cannot access '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:0a.0/sriov_numvfs': No such file or directory`. can you please check with either `82599, X522`  is it working?

Comment: Sorry, right now I have i350 only and was trying to enable sriov for running on qemu (though failed for pf vfio driver). Few google searches landed me here..

Comment: Not clear what you are stating, But simple answer with X710 and X522 the method you have suggested does not work. Reason is already shared in the answer. Good day

Answer (score 1):

If you've bound the vfio-pci driver to the PF, you have to enable
SRIOV support before you can add VFs.  This can be done by:

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/module/vfio_pci/parameters/enable_sriov
```

Once that is done, the vfio-pci kernel driver will allow you to
enable VFs.

For details, take a look at the `vfio_pci_sriov_configure()` function in
the Linux source for `drivers/vfio/pci/vfio_pci.c`.

```
static int vfio_pci_sriov_configure(struct pci_dev *pdev, int nr_virtfn)
{
    struct vfio_device *device;
    int ret = 0;

    might_sleep();

    if (!enable_sriov)
        return -ENOENT;
 ...
```

The `enable_sriov` variable is what gets set by writing to
the above sysfs file.

Alternatively, you can simply pass the parameter when loading
the vfio-pci kernel module:

```
sudo modprobe vfio-pci enable_sriov=1
```

Answer (score 0):

For Intel NIC like 82599, X522, and others VF (virtual function) ports can be created from PF (physical function) ports when it is either bind with `ixgbe` or `uio` driver like igb_uio. As configuring the Admin queue to set aside rx and tx queue and configure parameter for VF port requires the PF driver.

Unbind from ixgbe (kernel) |igb_uio (dpdk) loses the ability to do so. One maps to `vfio-pci` for basic functions and Host pass through. Hence the first step `dpdk-devbind.py --bind=vfio-pci 0000:02:00.0`, is causing the loose of SRIOV VF crete function.

Solution: please bind the device back to kernel ixgbe and create VF. The VF can be bind with `vfio-pci` for PCIe pass through or running on userspace.

Answer (score 0):

For me it works when I use `max_vfs` instead of `sriov_numvfs`
See https://github.com/intel/pf-bb-config/tree/v22.07

Try:

```
echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/max_vfs
```